# Android - Space added above TextView

Tags: java, android, layout, textview

When I have the following TextView, within a linear layout:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lbl_date"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:ems="5"
    android:text="what is up"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#062AEE"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

It displays like so, which is what I want:

[image]

However, when I add some more text, such that the text should wrap, the text wraps, but an mysterious top margin is added:

[image]

Anyone know why this is? I've tried setting a number of attributes to get rid of it, such as, `android:padding`, `android:layout_marginVertical`, `android:paddingVertical`, `android:layout_margin`, `android:layout_marginBottom`, `android:lineSpacingExtra`, `android:includeFontPadding="false"`. Any ideas how to get rid of that annoying space?

Thanks.

Here's some more of the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00292525"
    android:backgroundTint="#00242020"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingStart="60dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_like"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/date" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lbl_date"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:ems="5"
    android:text="what is up"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#062AEE"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

...
<!-- More ImageViews and TextViews -->
...

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Is your `LinearLayout` gravity set to `"bottom"`, by any chance?

Comment: Could you show your entire axml code?

Comment: I update the answer with more XML. No gravity is explicity set for the LinearLayout.

Comment: Try by removing `android:ems="5"` property from your `TextView`.